# What does カピカ mean?

Tags: words, definitions, onomatopoeia

I can't find this word in a dictionary.

It appears on a bag of rice I bought. The sentence is:

カピカ仕上げで、丁寧に磨いたきれいなお米です。

Is it a contraction of カピカピ, describing how the rice is dried out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This describes a specific method of polishing rice.

From [California's New Gold Rush - The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2003/10/08/dining/california-s-new-gold-rush.html)

> In one method, called kapika, polished rice is fine-sanded to produce a more lustrous finish

Comment: Yamamoto rice polisher KAPIKA http://www.calibrationplus.com/yamadp.html